# jQuery don't work in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

This code works fine in all browsers except Google Chrome, anybody know why?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $1 = $(".1"),
        $title = $(".admintitle"),
        $box = $(".uno"),
        flag = false,
        flag2 = false,
        height = $1.height();
    $title.click(function () {
        $1.animate({
            height: flag ? height : 40
        }, function () {
            $box.css('overflow', flag ? 'hidden' : 'visible')
            $title.css('background-position', flag ? '-254px 0px' : '0px 0px')
        });
        flag = !flag;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xQMHK/

Comment: What does "don't work" mean in this case? Please be specific.

Comment: We need a little more context. What is your HTML? What errors are you getting? Where?

Comment: Is it valid to use numbers for class names? I wouldn't use .1 - that's probably what s breaking

Comment: Your code is hard for me to read (and I program every day, all day).  Particularly things like `flag = !flag;` and `$1.animate` make this program hard to read for others (and yourself months from now).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xQMHK/

Comment: @user1477388 - If you can't read `flag = !flag`, I hope your everyday coding is just a hobby ?

Comment: @adeneo Please, you know that isn't good programming.  I wouldn't write code like that...

Comment: @user1477388 - I would! It actually looks fine to me ?

Comment: @adeneo I assume you also defend using numbers as variable names?  Come on, that's programming 101.

Comment: Numbers aren't valid as variable names, but `$1` is not a number, it's like `flag1` or `element10`, makes no difference !

Comment: @adeneo Whatever, goodluck reading abstract variable names.

Comment: I have to be with adeneo on this, `flag = !flag` is just correct.

Comment: Agreed `flag = ! flag` is fine with me, it makes perfect sense...

Comment: I'd love to see how @user1477388 would write `flag = !flag`.  Would it be... `if (flag === true) { flag = false; } else { flag = true; }`?

Comment: @Archer It's as simple and readable as `flag = (flag ? false : true);`.  That is so much easier to understand; but, whatever, you're the one who has to read your code.

Comment: @user1477388 That's right - thanks for pointing that out.  Good luck with your coding :)

Comment: On the other hand, why complicate this -> http://jsfiddle.net/xQMHK/3/

Comment: @adeneo Don't - it'll just confuse him even more :rolleyes:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final code and correct is this

http://jsfiddle.net/xQMHK/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $1 = $(".admin"),
    $title = $(".admintitle"),
    $box = $(".uno"),
    flag = false,
    flag2 = false,
    height = $1.height();
$title.click(function () {
    $1.animate({
        height: flag ? height : 40
    }, function () {
        $box.css('overflow', flag ? 'hidden': 'visible')
        $title.css('background-position', flag ? '-254px 0px': '0px 0px')
    });
    flag = !flag;
});
});
```

thanks everybody really!

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is that you're using numbers as class values. That's not strictly prohibited, but it can require different selection tactics:

```
var $1 = $(".1")
```

becomes

```
var $1 = $('div[class~="1"]');
```

Comment: Using numbers as class names...  Talk about bending it until it breaks!  Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I offered that code as an example. Without seeing your HTML I'm just guessing.

Comment: ok, only change 1 2 and 3 for text and works fine. thanks http://jsfiddle.net/xQMHK/2/

Comment: Numbers as classes works fine, not that it's a good idea, but there shouldn't be any problems with that in any browser -> http://jsfiddle.net/Kxxgw/

Comment: Apparently not in Chrome. Did you read the comment above yours?

Comment: Dunno. I was grasping at straws.

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome, but why are those classes there to begin with, do you really need three classes to reference the same god damn element ?